# How to fix Unity WebRequest Unknown error

Tags: php, unity-game-engine

I have problem with the code below when I do request to my laravel api in unity.

I added this headers to location ~ .php$ in conf

```
add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' "*";
add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, PUT,OPTION';
add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' "true";
add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' "x-authorization, Content-Type, Accept, X-Access-Token, X-Application-Name, X-Request-Sent-Time";
```

I have also set response headers in filter php app::After function.
php laravel

```
    $response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Headers','x-authorization, Content-Type');
    $response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Methods','GET, POST, PUT, OPTIONS');
    $response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin','*');
```

c#

```
    WWWForm form = new WWWForm();
    form.AddField("email", email_id);
    form.AddField("password", password);
    www2.certificateHandler = new 
    AcceptAllCertificatesSignedWithASpecificKeyPublicKey();
    www2.chunkedTransfer = true;
    yield return www2.SendWebRequest();
    Debug.Log("downloadHandler Text : " + www2.downloadHandler.text);
    Debug.Log("responseCode : " + www2.responseCode);
    Debug.Log("isDone : " + www2.isDone);
    Debug.Log("method : " + www2.method);
```

Debug is
downloadHandler Text :
responseCode : 0
isDone : True
method : POST
error: Unknown error

I think there would be a settings needs to change in the ubuntu server. From my understanding it is ssl issue that unity wants to know the servers certificate. Could you please help? Thanks a lot.

Comment: ive had response 0 for other reasons, such as theres no hint of a URL in your c# code, I in fact ended up writing a loop to retry ever 3 seconds or so in event of 0 response code because sometimes it did it because it could.. the fact you are thinking its a cert issue implies https, but it can also be dns issues, etc

Comment: aren't you suppose to use UnityWebRequest, because all the WWW code is going to be deleted in the future?